# Nivida Graphics Driver Black Screen Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

I'm new to Linux, Ubuntu, and command line stuff so bare with me as best you can. I scoured the internet and found some workarounds but I have yet to find an actual fix.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 via USB EFI on my Macbook 7,1. After starting it up it was timing out waiting for Nouveau to boot. I was able to get through to the desk top via `nomodeset` in the grub menu. I installed all prompted updates via a wired Ethernet connection and checked for the appropriate drivers in the terminal and received:

```
MacBookPro:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/0000:04:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000008A0sv0000106Bsd000000C2bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : MCP89 [GeForce 320M]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000014E4d0000432Bsv0000106Bsd0000008Dbc02sc80i00
vendor   : Broadcom Limited
model    : BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (AirPort Extreme)
driver   : bcmwl-kernel-source - distro non-free
```

I installed and updated the recommended drivers in terminal, rebooted, and was presented with a black screen, no cursor, no terminal (that I could find), nothing. So I was able to get to terminal through root in grub's recovery menu and wiped Nvidia using `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` successfully. I assume the OS then defaulted back to Nouveau and I was about to boot through to the desktop using `nomodeset` once again.

*My question is what can I do to fix either driver so I don't have to use terminal to start the computer?* I'd prefer Nvidia from what I've read but I can get it to work. I've found questions regarding removing Nvidia, and `nomodeset` for nouveau but I haven't found one addressing if neither works so I apologize if this is a belabored point.

**Hardware:**

```
MacBookPro:~$ inxi -ABCDFG
System:    Host: smoore-MacBookPro Kernel: 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64 bits: 64
Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Apple product: MacBookPro7 1 v: 1.0 serial: N/A
Mobo: Apple model: Mac-F222BEC8 serial: N/A
UEFI: Apple v: MBP71.88Z.003F.B00.1802021458 date: 02/02/18
Battery    BAT0: charge: 46.9 Wh 96.8% condition: 48.4/62.9 Wh(77%)
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core2 Duo P8800 (-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
       clock speeds: max: 2660 MHz 1: 1219 MHz 2: 1502 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA MCP89 [GeForce 320M]
       Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
       drivers: fbdev,nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
       Resolution: 1280x800@76.00hz
       OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 128 bits)
       version: 3.3 Mesa 18.2.
Audio:     Card NVIDIA MCP89 High Def. Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-45-generic
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom Limited BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
driver: wl
IF: wlp2s0 state: dormant mac: 
Card-2: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
driver: tg3
IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 240.1GB (3.6% used)
ID-1: /dev/sda model: SSD2SC240G1SA754 size: 240.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 219G used: 8.1G (4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 70.0C mobo: N/A
       Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 237 Uptime: 26 min Memory: 1987.4/3687.9MB
       Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

For what it's worth, I can't get the wireless driver to work either. Thank you in advance.